# Passing a rails variable to a js file

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails

I have a js file where I want to pass some Rails variable to such as url. What I do is:

```
#main.haml.html

<script type="text/javascript">
  var myUrl = <%=some_url%>;
</scirpt>

#script1.js
$.ajax({
  method: 'POST',
  url: myUrl,
  success: function(data) {
    //..........
  },
  error: function(a, b, c) {
        //..........
  }
});
```

I think it seems the proper way of doing this. Is this the idiomatic way of doing it? Is there a better way?

Comment: A better place for this questions would be codereview:  http://codereview.stackexchange.com/.  But I will offer this:  There's nothing specifically wrong with what you are doing - as this ajax method was created for that purpose.  However, you want to think about proper code organization.  Will you have a lot of ajax calls?  Is your javascript file growing in size?  You don't want to have scattered ajax calls all over the place within an increasingly complex javascript file.

Answer (score 1):

There's an episode on Rails Casts about this topic [here](http://railscasts.com/episodes/324-passing-data-to-javascript)

generally you can put execute scripts to put variable under window object or create a html div to just to hold data. Since these are more static to the browser environment

Comment: isn't that the same thing as what I do?